# How to manipulate an equation so that it is in terms of a certain variable

Tags: functions, code-request

For example, I have an equation

$$z = \frac{(1+a)}{(1+b)} + 3x + 4y^2$$

I have a new variable where $$R = \frac{(1+a)}{(1+b)}$$

Is there a function or code where I can tell *Mathematica* to transform all $\frac{(1+a)}{(1+b)}$ as $R$?

So that $$z = R +3x + 4y^2$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Eliminate[{z == (1 + a)/(1 + b) + 3 x + 4 y^2, R == (1 + a)/(1 + b)}, {a, b}]
```

> -3 x - 4 y^2 + z == R

Or

```
z == (1 + a)/(1 + b) + 3 x + 4 y^2 /. (1 + a)/(1 + b) -> R
```

> z == R + 3 x + 4 y^2

Comment: Hi Kglr, thanks for the help

In a simple equation that works, however I have a fairly large equation where some of the (1+a)'s are not directly divided by (1+b)

Comment: @Russ, does the first method (`Eliminate`) work for your large equation?

Comment: No, because i think there is multiple "R"s in the equation